# Android Studio Emulator has terminated Error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, avd-manager

I know this question was already asked sometimes, but the solutions didn't help me... The emulator worked perfectly some hours ago, but then following message came up when i tried to start the it:

[image]

**Setting of the current AVD:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**What I have tried so far:**

- check storage in C drive (18 GB)
- checked if HAXM installer was installed and also reinstalled it
- launching as cold boot
- changed "Launch in a tool window" in the emulator settings
- tried to reinstall android studio
- deleted the emulator and created new ones
- restarting my computer

I also read that it helps to enable the device frame in the AVD settings. But apparently I am not able to do this. If I enable the checkbutton and click on finish and open the settings again, the checkbutton is not enabled. Maybe that could be the solution. Image:

[image]

I recognised, that if I install a new AVD, it takes just like 2 seconds. Before, an installation window popped up and it installed 1 GB. That is not happening any more.

**Here are the SDK tools I have installed:**

[image]

One point I should add is, that the emulator is starting for one second with a black screen and then crashes with that error. Before crashing, a pop up message shows up on the top of the emulator that says: "**Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed**".

It is weird, because I had the problem some days ago as well, but back then the reason was that I needed to install the HAXM installer and the problem was solved.
I hope someone can help me! Thank you in advance!